# Athena (Presto) string to date conversion

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I have the following string: `'2019-05-17 04:44:00:000'`. I want to convert it to a date so that I can query my table based on the timestamp.

I've tried the following which results in an error:

```
select street, city,
from_iso8601_timestamp(starttime)
from mydata where subtype='X';
INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "2019-05-17 04:44:00:000" is 
malformed at " 04:44:00:000"

SELECT street, city, date_parse(starttime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
from mydata where subtype='X';
INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "2019-05-17 04:44:00:000" is malformed at " 04:44:00:000"
```

What is the correct way to convert this in Athena? Is there a millisecond parameter?

Comment: Per standard timestamp format, milliseconds should go after decimal point, not a colon. This is why you need to provide a custom format.

Answer (score 8):

You can parse the given string with the following pattern.

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s:%f'
```

The %f stand for fraction of a second and resolves up to microseconds.

Overall this would lead to the following query.

```
SELECT date_parse('2019-05-17 04:44:00:000','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s:%f')
```

For more information on that, you can have a look at the [official docs](http://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#date_parse).